# how to implement an Drop Down List for iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, drop-down-menu, uipickerview, nscombobox

I searched about UIPickerView and NSComboBox , I really don't understand the difference between these two !!! can anyone tell me what is the best way to show an Drop down list in xcode .

I saw the picker view but I think it is too much coding for a dropdown list !!!!

thank you

Comment: NSComboBox isn't available on iOS.

Comment: hey @milad i think you mean in your application and not in xcode.

Comment: yeah I mean dropdown for apps inside xcode ... !

Answer (score 2):

For Drop Down List you can implement picker View.It takes very less coding effort.
If you want to implement it like a drop down then you might take think to create a view which will have a label and a button (like in drop down) and on that button click show a table view.
This will take a good coding effort.

Comment: +1. It really is much less work to use a pickerview than to roll your own drop down list. User are also familiar with the pickerview paradigm by now.

Comment: But the pickerview is not really good, because it takes a lot of space in the gui and will probably overlap texts to the top and bottom. I can't believe that apple doesn't support a dropdown for ios ?